# HttpContext.IsPostNotification is false when Compilation debug is false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC project HttpContext.IsPostNotification is false when

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

HttpContext.IsPostNotification is true when

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

My controller "HomeController.cs"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Learning.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
            ViewBag.PostNotification = HttpContext.IsPostNotification;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

My View "Index.cshtml"

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@ViewBag.PostNotification
```

MVC application runs in Windows Server (developing in Windows 7), IIS7 Integrated Pipeline mode.

I want to move my application to production, but HttpContext.IsPostnotification is false when set to

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with PostNotification value?

Comment: when debug=false; bundling and minifacation will be applied in MVC.

Comment: @malkam I want to execute my logic after after an HttpApplication event has finished processing. We have not configured bundling and minification.

Answer (score 1):

Using `HttpContext.IsPostNotification` in an action method is meaningless. The `IsPostNotification` is meant to be used with `HttpContext.CurrentNotification` [to distinguish between *Main* and *Post* HttpApplication Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.currentnotification%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
    }

    // Main Event handler
    void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Context.CurrentNotification Is "AcquireRequestState"
        //Context.IsPostNotification Is "False"
    }

    // Post Event handler
    void Application_PostAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Context.CurrentNotification Is "AcquireRequestState"
        //Context.IsPostNotification Is "True"
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you want to detect an `HttpApplication` event completion, then you can just put your code in the event handler, unless this event handler is registered with other events, then you will need to use `CurrentNotification` and `IsPostNotification` to detect which event fired the handler.