# POST request with XML content is always null C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Using:  .NET Framework 4.7, Postman.
I make a POST request with Postman, Content-Type is set as "application/xml", to a .NET Framework 4.7 Web API.

The request body looks like this:

```
<Simple xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <example>hello</example>
</Simple>
```

The Controller API looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("test")]
public HttpResponseMessage test(Simple myRequest)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "helo world");
}
```

The class is:

```
public class Simple
{
    public string example { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason, the variable "myRequest" is always null!

I have also tried with the request body:

```
<myRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <example>hello</example>
</myRequest >
```

Do I need to add to Global.asax some formatting configuration or some setting anywhere?

Thanks!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111874/how-to-pass-xml-as-post-to-an-actionresult-in-asp-mvc-net

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `[FromBody]` attribute to the parameter:

```
public HttpResponseMessage test([FromBody] Simple myRequest)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "helo world");
}
```

Comment: It still does not convert :( Still null.