# How to convert blob data to string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following function to convert binary data to text:

```
public string BinaryToText(byte[] data)
{
     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding.UTF8);
     string text = reader.ReadTod();
     return text;
}
```

But I get an `OutOfMemoryException` for 30Mb data.

How can I solve this problem and convert data larger than 100Mb, using this or any better method?

Comment: do you intend to send this to a client>

Comment: If that data isn't really UTF8, then what you're doing is wrong anyway! Is the original data really UTF8?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003275/byte-to-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: If you data is UTF8 then use System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
public string BinaryToText(byte[] data)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
}
```

It will consume less memory. If it *still* runs out of memory, you'll need to read it in chunks - but how you are using the data will determine if that is possible. What are you doing with the returned string?

Also I will reiterate my earlier question: Is the input data *really* UTF8 data?

If you *can* handle the data being returned as multiple strings, you can do something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> BinaryToStrings(byte[] data, int maxStringLength)
{
    var buffer = new char[maxStringLength];

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int count = reader.Read(buffer, 0, maxStringLength);

            if (count == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            yield return new string(buffer, 0, count);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call that in a foreach loop like so:

```
foreach (string chunk in BinaryToStrings(data, 1024))
{
    // Do something with 'chunk'...
}
```