# Iterate through registry keys and read registry values

Tags: c#, registry

I want to iterate through the values of a specific path and read them.
I tried this

**Code updated**

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IntelliForms\Storage2", true);
        var names = key.GetValueNames();
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
                byte[] test = ObjectToByteArray(key.GetValue(names[i]));
                var value = Convert.ToBase64String(test);
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            };
```

Normally the string `value` should be an encrypted binary.

**Update:** So as @Peter Lillevold suggested I had to convert the array of bytes into a string.
To do so, I created this small function to convert the object `key.GetValue` into an array of bytes

```
public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;
            BinaryFormatter Binaryform = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream();
            Binaryform.Serialize(MemStream, obj);
            return MemStream.ToArray();
        }
```

and then converted to a string as @Peter suggested.

So after the convertion of the array of bytes it is supposed to return me a string of binary.
What I get is some weird combination of letters and digits but it is not binary.

Any help on this?

Comment: Because the `Value` is array of bytes. This can happen when the `RegistryValueKind` is `Binary`.

Comment: So what do you suggest? The answers given below doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The `ObjectToByteArray` call is superfluous. Since the type of `obj` is already `byte[]` it is enough to do a cast: `byte[] test = (byte[])obj`

Answer (score -1):

You get "System.Byte[]" because you take an instance of `byte[]` and calls ToString() on it. This will not convert the content of the byte array into text, for that you would use something like [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Encoding.UTF8.GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). More discussion on the topic in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003275/how-to-convert-byte-to-string).

Comment: Actually string value = key.GetValue(names[i]); is counted as an object. However it's console write writes System.Bytes[] which means an array of bytes. The converts you suggested don't seem to work, or I am doing something wrong

Comment: Yes, as I said, the result of `key.GetValue` yields an object of type byte array. `Console.Write` does the same as you did, calling `ToString` on the byte array, which in turn only results in the text "System.Byte[]". So... what do you mean "don't seem to work" ? Show some code of what you have tried. Also, given a binary value in registry, show what text you require to end up with.

Comment: Well, not exactly. You should be able to do `byte[] test = (byte[])key.GetValue(names[i]);`  Next, I want you to show an example of what you expect as output. My example using `ToBase64String` will give you (surprise!) a base64 representation of the byte array. If this is not what you're after, you must tell us what yo mean by "string of binary".

Comment: I wasn't able that is why I created that small function. I am able to do it now, I must have missed something in the beginning.
If I am understanding correctly what your question here then, in that path are stored our IE credentials which we choose to be stored (and auto-filled obviously). I have important credentials which if I loose it will take time to get them back again (e-mail credentials, personal cards credentials).
So my plans are: 1st to back them up, 2ond save them in a .txt file where they can be handled manually and re-written again to the registry.
I hope this covers your answer.

Comment: Sorry for not responding immediately and thank you for bearing with me here

Comment: No worries. Well, I was more after what you expect the string to look like after you have converted the byte array to string. Like this, say, given this array [1,2,3, 255] I want the string to look like "010203FF". In essence, define your own requirement.

Comment: Regardless of your coding problem, I would suggest you rather go to a commercial app, like 1password, which already does this in a highly secure manner. I would not trust myself to know all the necessary security knowledge related to storing passwords and other secrets. Note: I'm not in any way affiliated with 1password, I'm just a satisfied end-user :)

Comment: It actually is a project so involving a third party application isn't much what I want to do.
It should look like a binary: 0x01000000D08C9DDF01.
This is not my final goal. I want it in readable letters so a normal user can understand it but this is too much to ask.

Comment: Well, then I would say you are trying to open a can of worms (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/can_of_worms).

Comment: Sadly I know it but since there are applications that already do this, I thought that it wouldn't bother so much working on this project on public...