# Convert List<byte> to textBox.text

Tags: c#

I have a list declared as:

`List<byte> localData = new List<byte>();`

The list contains: `AA 01 53 54 41 43 4B 20 4F 56 45 52 46 4C 4F 57 34 5C` , where from `localData[2]` to `localData[15]` i have the text `STACK OVERFLOW`, that i will output to a textBox.

I cannot find a converter to do this for me, therefore i used a table do convert it in this way:

```
//Here i have all printable ascii chars.
char[] asciiTable = {' ','!','"','#','$','%','&','\'','(',')'etc... };
```

To print the data out i used:

```
textBox1.Clear();
for (i = 2; i < 16; i++)
{
     textBox1.Text += asciiTable[localData[i] - 32];
}
```

But i think there must be a better conversion method. Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Express for Desktop.

Edit: The suggested duplicate [How to convert byte[] to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003275/how-to-convert-byte-to-string) does not cover the use of List.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert byte\[\] to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003275/how-to-convert-byte-to-string)

Comment: There is no text but encoded text. Are you sure the encoding is ASCII? Code dealing with text should be very clear about which encoding it handles. (Requirement specifications should be, too.) It should also be clear about what to do in exceptional cases. (Substitution characters like ? and � is a "best effort," quiet error technique, while throwing an exception is an "all or nothing," "validate your assumptions" technique.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using LINQ:

```
List<byte> localData = new List<byte> { 0xAA, 0x01, 0x53, 0x54, 0x41, 0x43, 0x4B, 0x20, 0x4F, 0x56, 0x45, 0x52, 0x46, 0x4C, 0x4F, 0x57, 0x34, 0x5C };

string txt = new string(localData.Where((b, index) => index >= 2 && index <= 15)
                                 .Select(b => (char)b).ToArray());

WriteLine(txt); // STACK OVERFLOW
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want

```
textBox1.Text =
    System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(localData.ToArray());
```

`Encoding.Default` gives you the default ANSI encoding for your system. Do not confuse this with ASCII, which is a 7 bit encoding. The ANSI encoding is an 8 bit encoding, but the first 127 code points are the same as in the ASCII encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it, if you really only need ASCII, and only a subrange of your list:

```
List<byte> localData = new List<byte> { 0xAA, 0x01, 0x53, 0x54, 0x41, 0x43, 0x4B, 0x20, 0x4F, 0x56, 0x45, 0x52, 0x46, 0x4C, 0x4F, 0x57, 0x34, 0x5C };
textBox1.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(localData.GetRange(2, 14).ToArray());
```

If you need a conversion that supports characters outside the ASCII range, just change the code snippet to use the appropriate `Encoding` property.

Answer (score 0):

There is `System.Text.Encoding` class. It has a few properties for encoding and decoding texts. There should be a property `Default` that provides a default encoding (sufficient in most cases).

There is `GetString` method which takes a byte-array. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc(v=vs.110).aspx

You can call `ToArray` on your collection of byte and then feed it to `GetString`.

Example from MSDN

```
private static string ReadFromBuffer(FileStream fStream)
{
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    string output = String.Empty;
    Decoder decoder8 = enc8.GetDecoder();

    while (fStream.Position < fStream.Length) {
       int nBytes = fStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
       int nChars = decoder8.GetCharCount(bytes, 0, nBytes);
       char[] chars = new char[nChars];
       nChars = decoder8.GetChars(bytes, 0, nBytes, chars, 0);
       output += new String(chars, 0, nChars);                                                     
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all. The w.b suggestion does what i need. I'll refer to all the answers to learn C#, where i'm just beginning.