# Error While Converting Byte array to string in this algorithm

Tags: c#, arrays, exception, encoding

I want to read a file using `File.Readallbytes(myfile)` and to convert it to String like

```
string s=ByteArraytoString(File.Readallbytes(myfile));
```

but it doesn't really works for every file i choose, instead when the file is unicode it works file otherwise it doesn't ,so if any one can help me in this

```
 public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] bytes)
        {
            char[] chars = new char[(bytes.Length / sizeof(char))];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
            return new string(chars);
        }
        public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string s)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[s.Length * sizeof(char)];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(s.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return bytes;
        }
```

*so the exception is*: in **ByteArrayToString** method

> System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.
>      at System.Buffer.BlockCopy(Array src, Int32 srcOffset, Array dst, Int32 dstOffset, Int32 count)

i know this soloution posted like 1000 time but no one fix this problem in this code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so i solve the problem with this code 
it gives me error in `ByteArrayToString` because the bytes.length is odd
so what i do is to check if the bytes.length is even it do the code normally but when it's odd it add one byte as {0} to the end of bytes to it will be even

here is my code:

```
if (bytes.Length % 2 != 0) { 
                    byte[] newArray = new byte[bytes.Length + 1];
                    bytes.CopyTo(newArray, 1);
                    newArray[0] = byte.Parse("0");
                    bytes= newArray;
                }
```

Comment: Yes, you will avoid the exception this way, but if the file is not UTF-16, you will get a string with corrupted data.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to know what the encoding is for your file.  Then, you can just use the [System.Text.Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) class to conveniently convert the byte array to a string.

For instance, if your file is in UTF-8, you can simply do:

```
string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

If your encoding is different, just pick a different property from the `Encoding` class, but the pattern is the same.

**EDIT: Short explanation as to why OP's code did not work**

The code in your original post tries to interpret the byte array as if it was already in the same encoding as the `char` type, which is UTF-16.  So, unless your file happens to use UTF-16 encoding, it simply won't work.  Using the `Encoding` class is the way to go.

Comment: it's windows-1252 or what it called Westren

Comment: Then you can use `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252").GetString(bytes)`, or, if `windows-1252` is your default OS encoding, you can simply use `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes)`

Comment: I don't think OP looking for code that actually perform correct conversion ("solution posted like 1000 times"), but rather in fixing errors in code provided. Otherwise it should simply be duplicate.

Comment: @Alexei: His code can't be fixed because it's designed to work with UTF-16 only.  The fix is to use the `Encoding` class. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: If "use `Encoding`" is the answer you should have simply VTC as duplicate of standard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003275/how-to-convert-byte-to-string. I have no idea why OP asked fr fixing code they provided, but *to me* this question in not about correct implementation but rather why give node does not work (I completely agree that `Encoding` is the way to go, so I'm not planning to remove my downvote on question/answer).

Comment: @Alexei: Agreed. I marked as duplicate.  And I did edit my answer to make it clear that his code is UTF-16 specific.  I think OP really needs to understand that.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you try with default encoding
see below snippet

```
var strString = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(File.Readallbytes(myfile));
```

Comment: Why OP should "try" to do that? And how your suggestion is different from other answer?

Comment: because i dont know what kind of files i'm going to choose maybe unicode or utf-8 or what ever

Comment: @MohemmadAlBughdadi please make sure to read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html