# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, linq-to-dataset

Queried my SQL database to fetch details into Dataset when converting the Datatable to Dataview by filtering, since being newbie to Linq, am receiving the basic conversion error.

Code:

```
DataView cktDv = (from clounceform in dsclounceForms.Tables["Table2"].AsEnumerable()
                                         where clounceform.Field<string>("Form_FileType_ID").Equals("5")
                                         select clounceform).CopyToDataTable().AsDataView();
```

Exception is

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.String'.
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ReferenceField(Object value)
at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
at ClounceFormsSuite.Design.CreateFormDesign.<>c.<CreateForm>b__12_0(DataRow bounceform) in myprojectfolderpath\CreateFormDesign.xaml.cs:line 115
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Data.DataTableExtensions.LoadTableFromEnumerable[T](IEnumerable`1 source, DataTable table, Nullable`1 options, FillErrorEventHandler errorHandler)
at System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
at ClounceFormsSuite.Design.CreateFormDesign.CreateForm(String[] cktFileContent, String filePath, String formID) in myprojectfolderpath\CreateFormDesign.xaml.cs:line 114
at ClounceFormsSuite.Design.CreateFormDesign.UserControl_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in myprojectfolderpath\CreateFormDesign.xaml.cs:line 70
```

I couldnt proceed further i infact changed the casting of string to int and gives different error which is misleading me more 
When tried casting to int

```
DataView cktDataView = (from clounceform in dsclounceForms.Tables["Table2"].AsEnumerable()
                                         where clounceform.Field<int>("Form_FileType_ID") == 5
                                         select clounceform).CopyToDataTable().AsDataView();
```

error:

```
 Specified cast is not valid.
```

Comment: Maybe this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003275/how-to-convert-byte-to-string

Comment: What DataType is `Form_FileType_ID` in your Database?

Comment: It in an int datatype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data is a `byte`, not a `string` and not an `int`. Thus, you need to use `Field<byte>(...)`:

I suspect this will work:

```
where clounceform.Field<byte>("Form_FileType_ID") == (byte)5
```

Comment: It worked but  why it is not working being an int datatype it is not converting when i cast it.

Comment: @ArulManivannan because it **isn't** an `int`. You can't unbox things to something that they aren't.

Comment: @ArulManivannan: I can see why this confusing.  It is not obvious why `int i = 5; byte b = (byte)i;` is legal whereas `object i = 5; byte b = (byte)i;` is not.  The thing you are missing is that the cast operator uses one syntax for two very different operations.  Eric Lippert's article, [Representation and identity](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/), does an excellent job explaining the distinction.

Comment: @Brian, So glad to clear out my misunderstanding. Thanks.