# Handling intent callback Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android-intent, xamarin.forms

I basically want to be able to implement a feature for an android app to open a text file and read the contents to a string variable. I can handle this using android and Java but with forms I don't know how to go about it. I'm guessing dependency injection but a little guidance would do.

Comment: I think App links are what you looking for? https://blog.xamarin.com/deep-link-content-with-xamarin-forms-url-navigation/

Comment: @Rohit not exactly. I just want to select a text file with my app and read the text file.

Comment: do you want to do it via file picker?

Comment: @Rohit yes. Exactly

Comment: @Rohit sorry if the question had been phrased wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own file picker if required and use it via dependency service.

There is a plugin which does what you are asking for - [FilePicker Plugin for Xamarin and Windows](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.FilePicker).

This can let you handle file handling from your pcl project. 
The code is available in GitHub if you want to slightly customize it.

Eg :

```
private async Task PickFilesCommandHandler()
{
     var file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
     var fileEntity = new FileEntity
     {
         FileName = file.FileName,
         DataArray = file.DataArray
     };
}
```

Full example in [Github](https://github.com/rohitvipin/XFPDFMerge/blob/master/XFPDFMerge/XFPDFMerge/ViewModels/HomeViewModel.cs).

For byte array to string conversion have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1003275/1155650).

Or use the following method via `MemoryStream` :

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes)) 
{ 
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(ms)) 
    { 
        var str = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna try this out and get back to you.

Comment: Quick question, how do I get the text value if it is a txt file to string variable?

Comment: What you have is a byte array. Just convert the byte array to string. Updated the answer to include that as well.

Comment: yup. This Worked for me.

Comment: Would it be possible to filter the file to be selected, like image, video and stuff like that?

Comment: You can check the extension once it's picked. I'm not sure of the filter.

Comment: Yeah. Did that. Don't think it has a filter. Thanks though