# VB.NET TCP Server Socket Programming - Receiving String from Byte

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp

How to get string from this code instead of array of char ?

Client Code :

```
            stm = tcpClient.GetStream() 
            Dim ascenc As New ASCIIEncoding
            Dim byteData() As Byte = ascenc.GetBytes(strMessage(counter))
            Thread.Sleep(2000)
            Console.WriteLine("Transmitted ")
            stm.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length())
```

Server code :

```
Dim size As Integer = TcpSocket.Receive(bitData)
            Dim chars(size) As Char
            For i As Integer = 0 To size
                chars(i) = Convert.ToChar(bitData(i)) // i want to get the string directly, how ?
            Next
            Dim newString As New String(chars)
            Console.WriteLine(newString)
            strMessage(counter) = newString
```

Comment: [Tried](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172827.aspx) [googling](https://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-string-byte-array-vbnet) [at](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003275/how-to-convert-byte-to-string) [all?](http://www.convertdatatypes.com/Convert-Byte-Array-to-String-in-VB.net.html)

Answer (score 1):

You already have it implemented with your code I suggested:

```
Dim MyString As String = New String(MyArray)
```

If you want to convert the byte array you can use:

```
Dim MyString As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
```

Comment: He's already doing that, though: `Dim newString As New String(chars)`. He wants to convert the byte array instead, rather than having to iterate it to create a char array.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yeah thats why I edited i don't understand his problem. Then a simple:  Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)

Comment: That is what he wants, yes. I wrote so in my answer (except I used his method rather than the static property).

Comment: @VisualVincent Oh the page didn't refresh and I didn't see it. Upvote for the nice structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ASCIIEncoding` on the server as well. Just use its [**`GetString()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than `GetBytes()`.

```
Dim ascenc As New ASCIIEncoding
Dim newString As String = ascenc.GetString(bitData)
```