# .NET Get embedded Resource File

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resources, embedded-resource

I have an embedded Resource File:

[image]

I need to open it as a Stream.

What I've tried (did not work, stream is null):

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("client_secret.json"))
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

**Edit:** What I'm doing with it:

```
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("client_secret.json"))
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                  new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                  "user",
                  CancellationToken.None
                );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean Stream Philip? you want to stream that file to another client? or just open the file for access content of it?

Comment: @combo_ci I just want to open the file to access the contents, see above.  I updated my post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

Answer (score 10):

I solved this, I had to provide the full Namespace of the Resource:

```
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Project.Resources.client_secret.json"))
```

Answer (score 6):

Right-Click your Project in Solution Explorer -> Add -> New Item -> Resources File

Then double-click on the created file (e.g. Resource1.resx), and then add your `client_secret.json` to it. Now you can access to `client_secret.json` content with blow code. Note that if you put a json file to resource, when get the client_secret you get a byte[] and must [convert that to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003275/how-to-convert-byte-to-string)

```
 var foo= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Resource1.client_secret);
```

But if only add `.txt` file you can access to that file with:

```
var foo= Resource1.txtfile;
```