# Folder path from other dll

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have 2 projects. The main project and dll project.
In the dll project, I have files in the folder Data.

How can I get a relative file location (in the example Data\Test.txt) running from the main project?
[image: Img]

I try to load data from dll in the main project.

Comment: Is the File `Test.txt` configured to be copied to output/Data/Test.txt ?

Comment: Without knowing what you actually want to do, you may also try and embed the file.

Comment: No, it is not but can make it copied

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/44577716/982149

Comment: Fildor's linked Question is the way you should do this, developer op

Comment: Assuming `Test.cs` is a class, you could use `typeof(Test).Assembly.Location` to get its absolute path. Then append "\Data" to the end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)