# How can I decompress a stream in c# like this java snippet code?

Tags: java, c#, gzip, gzipstream

I'm trying to convert this java snippet code in c# but I'm a bit confused about it.
This is the java code:

My try is the following, but there are some errors in gis.Read, because it wants a char* and not a byte[] and in the String constructor for the same reason.

```
public static String decompress(InputStream input) throws IOException 
{
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 32;
    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(input, BUFFER_SIZE);
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = gis.read(data)) != -1) {
        string.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead));
    }
    gis.close();
    // is.close();
    return string.toString();
}
```

I expected to get a readable string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003275/how-to-convert-utf-8-byte-to-string

Comment: GZipStream Read method works with bytes. Check [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream.read?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transform the bytes to characters first. For that, you need to know the encoding.

In your code, you could have replaced `new String(data, 0, bytesRead)` with `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead)` to do that. However, I would handle this slightly differently.

`StreamReader` is a useful class to read bytes as text in C#. Just wrap it around your `GZipStream` and let it do its magic.

```
public static string Decompress(Stream input)
{
    // note this buffer size is REALLY small. 
    // You could stick with the default buffer size of the StreamReader (1024)
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 32;
    string result = null;
    using (var gis = new GZipStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress, leaveOpen: true))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(gis, Encoding.UTF8, true, BUFFER_SIZE))
    {
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To do a complete magic i used another GZipStream's constructor:
    new GzipStrem(input, CompressionMode.Decompress)
that's because i need to decompress the stream, not to compress. So if you want, please modify your answer to help other people with this problem. Thanks Again.