# C# - Generate a SHA/MD5 or similar signature from a MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument

Tags: c#, hash, mongodb-.net-driver, hmac, bson

I'm trying to generate a cache key from a mongo [bson query document](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDocument.htm). Is [GetHashCode()](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDocument_GetHashCode.htm) good for this purpose? Is there a better way to generate an actual MD5 or SHA hash given a bson document?

Answer (score 1):

In this [Microsoft Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/ensuring-data-integrity-with-hash-codes) they offer a good example of hashing a string with SHA256, the result is returned as a byte[], which can be turned into a string using [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003275/how-to-convert-utf-8-byte-to-string). Thus can be used in cache.

Comment: I'm looking for something that will produce the same hash despite the order of fields being different since this is a bson object. I could use the above to come up with a custom solution but I do not want to reinvent the wheel if its already done somewhere in the bson library code.