# How to get Sprint field data in C# from MS Project mpp file via MPXJ?

Tags: c#, windows, ms-project, sprint, mpxj

I'm working on a project where I have to extract data from mpp files, that are Sprint Project files. I'm using MPXJ, and now stuck as I cannot seem to find a way to retrieve data from the **'Sprint'** and **'Boad Status'** fields.

I have tried the **Task.getFieldByAlias()** method unsuccessfully and when I list the **ProjectFile.getCustomFields()** result, the problematic fields are not included there either.

I have also looked it up in the MPXJ documentation and I discovered that there is a **TaskField** enum type that has these elements and that **TaskContainer.getPopulatedFields()** returns with **Set<TaskField>** however when I list it in my code, **'Sprint'** and **'Board Status'** aren't in there either, even though in the mpp file they are not empty.

Does anyone know a way to extract data from those fields peferably via MPXJ? I'm even open to new ideas regarding the parser at this point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading task enterprise custom field values from mpp file using mpxj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68801757/reading-task-enterprise-custom-field-values-from-mpp-file-using-mpxj)

Comment: @RachelHettinger My problem is that it doesn't even finds that field and returns with null, so unfortunatelly no. Also, the fields I'm looking for aren't listed in the Project's Custom Fields.

Comment: Project doesn’t have a field named Sprint, so if it’s not a custom field then is it a custom name for a standard field such as Text1? If so, use the standard name to get the data.

Comment: @RachelHettinger I just tried iterating through these kind of field names, (Text1-Text30) with no luck. Also I forgot to mention, that this is a Sprint Project, not a Blank one.

Comment: @Daniel MPXJ doesn't currently support reading these fields, but I'm going to take a look over the next couple of days to see if I can add that support.

Comment: @JonIles Thank you very much! I'll try to check from time to time, but if you manage to add support of the fields, could you please notify me just in case?